# androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am facing the error once I changed

```
NavigationView navigationView = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView( 
   navigationView.getMenu().findItem( R.id.nav_view ) );
```

to

```
NavigationView navigationView  = (TextView) navigationView.getMenu().findItem( R.id.nav_view );
```

`MenuItemCompat.getActionView` is deprecated API that is why i changed but my app crashes.

Comment: What do you want to do? Please clear and also add your menu xml

Comment: `navigationView.getMenu().findItem` give you `MenuItem`. But probably you provide wrong id `R.id.nav_view`. You have messed your code.

Comment: it was nav_history I am fetching data from rest API which is integer value and I want to show in navigation drawer

Comment: Please edit your post and add menu xml

Comment: the MenuItemCompat.getActionView is deprecated API. It was working fine but that is why I do not want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_history).getActionView();
```

Comment: it is not working I want to show text in navigation drawer

Comment: for display text into navigation drawer you need to add menu file.             
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/iem"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_portrait_black"
        android:title="item1"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_brightness"
        android:title="item2"/>
  
</menu>                                                                                                                                         also add in Navigationview app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"

Comment: I have added everything works fine when I use   historyCount = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView( navigationView.getMenu().findItem( R.id.nav_history ) );   but MenuItemCompat.getActionView is deprecated api I want the alternative

Comment: use this new api,                                     `navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_history).getActionView();`                  I hope this helps you..

Comment: it works like a charm thank edit your answer So I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

ERROR: You can't cast NavigationView to TextView in 2nd Code Line

You can get that by method of `NavigationView.getMenu()`

```
Menu menuNav = mNavigationView.getMenu();
```

Then you can find specific item by

```
MenuItem logoutItem = menuNav.findItem(R.id.menu_logout);
```

See Official documentation for [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)

Comment: how can I show text  which I am getting from rest API

Comment: menuNav.findItem(R.id.menu_logout).setTitle(textfromAPI);

Answer (score 1):

Assume your `menu` contains a `MenuItem` with `ActionViewClass` as `TextView`. Then you can set text to your menu like below:

```
MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem( R.id.MENU_ITEM_ID );
TextView textView = (TextView) menuItem.getActionView();

//Set your text here
textView.setText(YOUR_TEXT);
```